# How to link outside of app directory in EB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been using the /tmp directory of elastic beanstalk to generate files that I would like to make available for users to download. However, I'm having some trouble linking properly to that folder from a view. Below is what I've tried:

```
<a href= <%= "/tmp/#{@project.id}/doc.kml" %> download>Download KML</a>
```

This filepath works in the project model and project controller pages, but not when accessed from the view. From the view page, it resolves as follows, with "no file found":

```
http://my_app_name.elasticbeanstalk.com/tmp/1/doc.kml
```

I believe this is pointing to the tmp folder of my app root directory, while I want to go up a level outside the app root for the tmp directory there. Is there a trick to accomplish this?

Comment: No if you want to serve static file with your http server - I guess you need to serve it with controller.

Comment: if your file is temporary per a request, you need to use app's tmp dir, if not you need to upload this file to another service like S3.

Comment: @NeverBe the file is temporary, but I have [not been able](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980478/how-can-i-create-a-tmp-directory-with-elastic-beanstalk) to write to the app's tmp dir in EB. I'd rather not put on S3, would prefer to use the app/tmp dir if you have advice on that

Comment: @MarekLipka, could you explain or link me to an explanation to serve with the controller?